# Magento 2: How to create configurable product Programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

I want to create a configurable product and assign some simple product to it. 
I have found lots of solution in the web but it's not working. 
Please let me know if any idea!!!

Thanks

Comment: via programmatically ?

Comment: yes. via programmatically.

Comment: is setConfigurableProductsData() function work in magento 2 ?

Answer (score 7):

This code has worked for me. it may be help you.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$configurable_product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$configurable_product->setSku('CONFIG_SKU'); // set sku
$configurable_product->setName('CONFIG PRODUCT NAME'); // set name
$configurable_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
$configurable_product->setStatus(1);
$configurable_product->setTypeId('configurable');
$configurable_product->setPrice(0);
$configurable_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1)); // set website
$configurable_product->setCategoryIds(array(2)); // set category
$configurable_product->setStockData(array(
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        )
);

// super attribute 
$size_attr_id = $configurable_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_size')->getId();
$color_attr_id = $configurable_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getId();

$configurable_product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array($color_attr_id, $size_attr_id), $configurable_product); //attribute ID of attribute 'size_general' in my store

$configurableAttributesData = $configurable_product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configurable_product);
$configurable_product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$configurable_product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
$configurableProductsData = array();
$configurable_product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
try {
    $configurable_product->save();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($ex->getMessage());
    exit;
}

$productId = $configurable_product->getId();

// assign simple product ids
$associatedProductIds = array(12,13,14);

try{
$configurable_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); // Load Configurable Product
    $configurable_product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds); // Setting Associated Products
    $configurable_product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $configurable_product->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    exit;
}
```

Comment: sorry... it is not work form me.

Comment: can you add the code ?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I refer to https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/_files/product_configurable.php
and it work!!

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me on Magento 2.3.5 with attribute codes `color` and `size` and presumes that you have already created simple products with color and size options.

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$product->setTypeId('configurable') 
        ->setStatus(1) // 1 = enabled, 2 = disabled
        ->setAttributeSetId(4) // 4 = default
        ->setName('Configurable test product')
        ->setSku('1000')
        ->setPrice(0)
        ->setTaxClassId(2) // 0 = None, 2 = Default product tax class
        ->setCategoryIds(array(2)) // 2 = Default category
        ->setDescription('test description')
        ->setShortDescription('test short description')
        ->setUrlKey('configurable-test-product')
        ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) // 1 = Default Website ID
        ->setStoreId(0) // 0 = Default store ID
        ->setVisibility(4); // 4 = Catalog & Search
                
        $product_resource = $product->getResource();
        $color_attribute = $product_resource->getAttribute('color');
        $size_attribute = $product_resource->getAttribute('size');
        $color_attribute_id = $color_attribute->getId();
        $size_attribute_id = $size_attribute->getId();
        $configurable_attributes = array('color', 'size'); // put here all configurable attributes you need and get their attribute IDs like I showed above
        $product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array($color_attribute_id, $size_attribute_id), $product); // assign attributes to configurable product
    
        $configurable_attributes_data = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
        $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
        $product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurable_attributes_data);

        $child_product_skus = array('1234','2345'); // add all child skus you need
        $child_products = explode(',', $child_product_skus);
        $child_ids = array();
        foreach ($child_products as $child_product) {
            $child_ids[] = $product->getIdBySku($child_product);
        }

        $product->setAssociatedProductIds($child_ids);

        $product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML); // or \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, depending on your need

// Define Zend Logger
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/create-product.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);


$simpleProduct = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create();
$productAttributeRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface');
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$atributeCode = ['color','size'];


$color = $productAttributeRepository->get('color');
$colorLabel = $color->getData('frontend_label');
$colorOptions = $color->getOptions();
array_shift($colorOptions);

$size = $productAttributeRepository->get('size');
$sizeLabel = $size->getData('frontend_label');
$sizeOptions = $size->getOptions();
array_shift($sizeOptions);


//print_r(json_decode(json_encode($color->getData('frontend_label')),true));die;
$attributeValues = [];
$configurableAttributesData = [];
foreach ($sizeOptions as $sizeOption) {
$sizeAttributeValues[] = [
'label' => $sizeLabel,
'attribute_id' => $size->getId(),
'value_index' => $sizeOption->getValue(),
];
//$sizeAttributeValues[] = $sizeOption->getValue();
}
$configurableAttributesData[] = [
'attribute_id' => $size->getId(),
'code' => $size->getAttributeCode(),
'label' => $size->getStoreLabel(),
'position' => '0',
'values' => $sizeAttributeValues,
];

foreach ($colorOptions as $colorOption) {
$colorAttributeValues[] = [
'label' => $colorLabel,
'attribute_id' => $color->getId(),
'value_index' => $colorOption->getValue(),
];
//$colorAttributeValues[] = $colorOption->getValue();
}
$configurableAttributesData[] =
[
'attribute_id' => $color->getId(),
'code' => $color->getAttributeCode(),
'label' => $color->getStoreLabel(),
'position' => '0',
'values' => $colorAttributeValues,

];


foreach ($sizeOptions as $sizeOption) {
   foreach ($colorOptions as $colorOption) {
$sizeValue = $sizeOption->getValue();
$colorValue = $colorOption->getValue();
//echo "<br> size $sizeValue : Color $colorValue <br>";
$rand = rand(10,100);
$simpleProduct = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class);
$attributeSetId = $simpleProduct->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
$simpleProduct->setTypeId('simple')
->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId)
->setWebsiteIds([1])
->setName('Simple_Product1 - ' . $sizeOption->getLabel(). '-'.$colorOption->getLabel())
->setSku('simple_2' .$sizeOption->getLabel(). '-'.$colorOption->getLabel())
->setPrice(10)
->setColor($colorValue)
->setSize($sizeValue ) // Set the 'color' attribute option value
->setVisibility(1)  
->setStatus(1)
->setWeight(2)
->setCategories('Default')
->setStockData(['use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 'qty' => 100, 'is_qty_decimal' => 0, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);

$simpleProduct = $productRepository->save($simpleProduct);
$associatedProductIds[] = $simpleProduct->getId();
$msg = 'Created Simple Product. Product ID: ' . $simpleProduct->getId();
echo $msg . '<br />';
$logger->info($msg);

}
}
$optionsFactory = $objectManager->create(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Factory::class);
$configurableOptions = $optionsFactory->create($configurableAttributesData);

$configurableProduct = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class);
$extensionConfigurableAttributes = $configurableProduct->getExtensionAttributes();
$extensionConfigurableAttributes->setConfigurableProductOptions($configurableOptions);
$extensionConfigurableAttributes->setConfigurableProductLinks($associatedProductIds);
$rand = rand(10,100);
$configurableProduct->setTypeId('configurable')
//->setId(1)
->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId)
->setWebsiteIds([1])
->setName('Test Configurable Product1'.$rand)
->setSku('test-configurable-33-'.$rand )
->setUrlKey('test-configurable-22-'.$rand)
->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
->setStockData(['use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 'qty' => 100 ,'is_in_stock' => 1]);
$configurableProduct->setExtensionAttributes($extensionConfigurableAttributes);
$configurableProduct = $productRepository->save($configurableProduct);$msg = 'Created Configurable Product. Product ID: ' . $configurableProduct->getId();
echo $msg . '<br />';
$logger->info($msg);




?>
```