# Product is not being created programmatically with quantity in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product

I am trying to create product programmatically with code. Product is successfully created but without quantity. How can add quantity.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
                $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
                $product->setSku('conf5'); // Set your sku here
                $product->setName('conf5'); // Name of Product
                $product->setAttributeSetId(9); // Attribute set id
                $product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
                $product->setWeight(10); // weight of product
                $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
                $product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
                $product->setTaxClassId(3); // Tax class id
                $product->setTypeId('configurable'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
                $product->setDescription('descript');
                $product->setShortDescription('shortdes');
                $product->setPrice(100);*/ // price of product
                $product->setStockData(
                    array(
                        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                        'manage_stock' => 1,
                        'is_in_stock' => 1,
                        'qty' => 9
                    )
                );
```

Comment: Here is example of create configure product programatically with quantity please check  :https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201587/magento-2-how-to-create-configurable-product-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I usually do the following in my data fixtures:

```
/** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface $stockItem */
$stockItem = $objectManager->create(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface::class);
$stockItem->setQty(100)->setIsInStock(true);
$extensionAttributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
$extensionAttributes->setStockItem($stockItem);

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository */
$productRepository = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
$productRepository->save($product);
```

Comment: I had tried this but still quantity not update.

Answer (score 0):

This solve my issue
 `$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => 23, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);`