# How can we add configurable products programmatically in magento 2?

Tags: configurable-product

How can we add configurable products programmatically in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [Magento 2: How to create configurable product Programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201587/magento-2-how-to-create-configurable-product-programmatically)
You can base on this :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Factory;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
use Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface;
use Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap;
\Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getInstance()->reinitialize();
require __DIR__ . '/configurable_attribute.php';
/** @var ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository */
$productRepository = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()
    ->create(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
/** @var $installer CategorySetup */
$installer = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(CategorySetup::class);
/* Create simple products per each option value*/
/** @var AttributeOptionInterface[] $options */
$options = $attribute->getOptions();
$attributeValues = [];
$attributeSetId = $installer->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'Default');
$associatedProductIds = [];
$productIds = [10, 20];
array_shift($options); //remove the first option which is empty
foreach ($options as $option) {
    /** @var $product Product */
    $product = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(Product::class);
    $productId = array_shift($productIds);
    $product->setTypeId(Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
        ->setId($productId)
        ->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId)
        ->setWebsiteIds([1])
        ->setName('Configurable Option' . $option->getLabel())
        ->setSku('simple_' . $productId)
        ->setPrice($productId)
        ->setTestConfigurable($option->getValue())
        ->setVisibility(Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)
        ->setStatus(Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        ->setStockData(['use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 'qty' => 100, 'is_qty_decimal' => 0, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
    $product = $productRepository->save($product);
    /** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item $stockItem */
    $stockItem = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item');
    $stockItem->load($productId, 'product_id');
    if (!$stockItem->getProductId()) {
        $stockItem->setProductId($productId);
    }
    $stockItem->setUseConfigManageStock(1);
    $stockItem->setQty(1000);
    $stockItem->setIsQtyDecimal(0);
    $stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
    $stockItem->save();
    $attributeValues[] = [
        'label' => 'test',
        'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId(),
        'value_index' => $option->getValue(),
    ];
    $associatedProductIds[] = $product->getId();
}
/** @var $product Product */
$product = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(Product::class);
/** @var Factory $optionsFactory */
$optionsFactory = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(Factory::class);
$configurableAttributesData = [
    [
        'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId(),
        'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
        'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
        'position' => '0',
        'values' => $attributeValues,
    ],
];
$configurableOptions = $optionsFactory->create($configurableAttributesData);
$extensionConfigurableAttributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
$extensionConfigurableAttributes->setConfigurableProductOptions($configurableOptions);
$extensionConfigurableAttributes->setConfigurableProductLinks($associatedProductIds);
$product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionConfigurableAttributes);
$product->setTypeId(Configurable::TYPE_CODE)
    ->setId(1001)
    ->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId)
    ->setWebsiteIds([1])
    ->setName('Configurable Product')
    ->setSku('configurable')
    ->setVisibility(Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
    ->setStatus(Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->setStockData(['use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
$productRepository->save($product);
```