Is it possible to use Magento's import functionality to create multiple configurable products using REST api
I want to create a custom REST api where we can pass multiple configurable products data (similar to what we use in import.csv), and it will create the configurable as well as the child products based on the data provided.
During product import Magento reads import csv file, and creates configurable products alongside its child products for the given configurations.
Is it possible to extract the method Magento uses to import products , and use them in the custom api ? If so, how can it be done ?

You can use the custom code of create item in your rest api method with possible options pass in api parameter and than you can create create configurable item with child. Reference: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201587/magento-2-how-to-create-configurable-product-programmatically Get your queries solved over here. Thank You!
